# When is it better to generate a static page or dynamically generate?

Tags: performance

The title pretty much sums up my question.

When is it more efficient to generate a static page, that a user can access, as apposed to using dynamically generated pages that query a database? As in what situations would one be better than the other.

Comment: A static page is almost always faster. But it is not a good engineering choice.

Comment: Of course, which is why I had the question. When would it be better to do one over the other? The performance has to take a hit at some point in high use situations, since you're constantly managing files rather than small pieces of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve up a static page, your web server just needs to read the page off the disk and send it. Virtually no processing will be required. If the page is frequently accessed, it will probably be cached in memory, so even the disk access will not be needed.

Generating pages dynamically obviously has more overhead. There is a cost for every DB access you make, no matter how simple the query is. (On a project I worked on recently, I measured a minimum overhead of 0.7ms for each query, even for `SELECT 1;`) So if you can just generate a static page and save it to disk, page accesses will be faster. How much faster? It just depends on how much work is being done to generate the page dynamically. We don't know what you are doing, so we can't comment on that.

Now, if you generate a static page and save it to disk, that means you need to *re-generate* it every time the data which went into generating that page changes. If the data changes more often than the page is actually accessed, you could be doing *more* work rather than less! But in most cases, that's a very unlikely situation.

More likely, the biggest problem you will experience from generating static pages and saving them to disk is coding (and maintaining) the logic for re-generating the pages whenever necessary. You will need to keep track of *exactly* what data goes into each page, and in *every* place in the code where data can be changed, you will need to invoke re-generation of all the relevant pages. If you forget just one, then your users may be looking at stale data some of the time.

If you mix dynamic generation per-request and caching generated pages on disk, then your code will be harder to read and maintain, because of mixing the two styles.

And you can't really cache generated pages on disk in certain situations -- like responding to POST requests which come from a form submission. Or imagine that when your users invoke certain actions, you have to send a request to a 3rd party API, and the data which comes back from that API will be used in the page. What comes back from the API may be different each time, so in this case, you need to generate the page dynamically each time.

Answer (score 1):

Static pages (or better resources) are filled with content, that does not change or at least not often, and does not allow further queries on it: About Page, Contact, ...

In this case it doesn't make any sense to query these pages. On the other side we have Data (e.g. in a Database) and want to query it/give the user the opportunity to query it. In this case you give the User a page with the possibility to specify the query and return a rendered page with the dynamically generated data.

In my opinion it depends on the result you want to present to the user. Either it is only an information or it is the possibility to query a Datasource. The first result is known before you do something, the second (query data) is known after you have the query parameters, which means you don't know the result beforehand (it could be empty or invalid).

It depends on your architecture, but when you consider that GET Requests should be idempotent it should be also easy to cache dynamic Pages with a Proxy, and invalidate the cache, when something new happens to the data which is displayed on the cached path. In this case one could save a lot of time, because the system behaves like the cached pages would be static, but instead coming from the filesystem, they come from your memory, which is really fast.

Cheers
Laidback